# How to add title and Done button on toolbar in a modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I try to present a modal view (InfoViewController) from a navigation view controller(DateViewController).

I add a toolbar on top of InfoViewContoller's view. Now I want to add a title "Info" and a "Done" button on the toolbar.(The Done button will perform the infoDismissAction method)

Can anyone give me som tips? Thanks a lot!

Here's code of DateViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "InfoViewController.h"
@interface DateViewController : UIViewController 
{
    InfoViewController *infoViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) InfoViewController *infoViewController;
@end
```

DateViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)modalViewAction:(id)sender{    
    if (self.infoViewController == nil)
        self.infoViewController = [[[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
                                   NSStringFromClass([InfoViewController class]) bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:self.infoViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc{
    if (self.infoViewController != nil)
    {
        [infoViewController release];
    }
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info"  style:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self  action:@selector(modalViewAction:)] autorelease];
    [modalBarButtonItem release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Here's InfoViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)infoDismissAction:(id)sender{
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIToolbar *toolBar;
    toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
    [toolBar sizeToFit];        
    [self.view addSubview:toolBar]; 
    [toolBar release];
    [backButton release];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       UIToolbar *toolBar;
            toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
            toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
            toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
            [toolBar sizeToFit];      
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"INFO" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(InfoAction:)] autorelease];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DONE" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneAction:)];


            NSArray *barButton  =   [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flexibleSpace,infoButton,flexibleSpace,doneButton,nil];
            [toolBar setItems:barButton];

        [self.view addSubview:toolBar];
        [toolBar release];
        [barButton release];
        barButton = nil;
        [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to use flexibleSpace. But I mean how to add a "Info" title instead of a "Info" bar button.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend setting up another UINavigationController with your InfoViewController and present the navigation controller as your modal view.

To answer your question you'd want to fill in your UIToolbar like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIToolbar *toolBar;
  toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
  toolBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50);
  toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
  [toolBar sizeToFit];        
  [self.view addSubview:toolBar]; 
  [toolBar release];

  UIBarButtonItem* bbiInfo = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(tappedInfoButton)];
  UIBarButtonItem* flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
  UIBarButtonItem* bbiDone = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(tappedDoneButton)];
  NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:bbiInfo, flexibleSpace, bbiDone, nil];
  [toolBar setItems:items];

  [items release];
  [bbiInfo release];
  [flexibleSpace release];
  [bbiDone release];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I know how to use flexibleSpace. But I mean how to add a "Info" title instead of a "Info" bar button.

Comment: UIBarButtonItem* infoTitle = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];

Comment: Thank you:P  
But if there is any way to put the infoTitle right at the center of toolBar?

I tried the following code, but could not put infoLabel at center.
NSArray* items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flexibleSpace,infoLabel, flexibleSpace, bbiDone, nil];
  [toolBar setItems:items];

Comment: That's one of the reasons I try to avoid a UIToolbar. A UINavigationBar handles that for you. If you stick with a UIToolbar I'd suggest using a UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace and playing with it's width to your liking.

Comment: My coworker @slaunchman prefers this approach, the reasons for which will become clear in the future.